# TFS Build - get source code by label issues

Tags: build, tfs, tfsbuild

I have an issue that I want to share with you and ask for advice.

Let's say I have a project in TFS with a source code folders and folder with deployment scripts. Folders structure:

-- TFS

---- PROJECT

--------DEPLOYMENTSCRIPTS

--------SOURCE

*DeploymentScripts* folder is a container for custom deployment scripts that are being executed by TFS Build process.

*Source* - is a folder with a source code where for each new release I create a label to use it later for deployment.

I have a build definition configured to takes files from both folders, so I expect that TFS will download the content of both folders each time I trigger a build:

[image: build definition - source settings]

And this perfectly works when TFS build takes the latest version: it takes everything, builds and deploys.

The issue appears once I configure what label to take:

[image: build definition - label]

TFS downloads **only** the content of *Source* folder **ignoring** *DeploymentScripts*. I suppose that this happens because we use labels only for *Source* folder and not in *DeploymetScripts* (the content of this folder is static, there are no any changes). I know, that if I make *DeploymentScripts* a sub-folder of *Sources* that will fix my issue, but I want to keep it separate (for example, if I later create a bunch of branch folders I don't want to copy deployment to each specific folder, I want to have as a one instance) and try to find a solution for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Either apply your label at the root level, or start your build using a date or changeset number.

Another approach would be to use branching rather than labels, and set up your build to allow you to pass in the name of the branch to be built.

I no longer use labels, I can't think of a situation where they would be useful to me these days.

Comment: We find labels useful when we create a new branch for release and performing stabilization and bug fixes.

Comment: We use release branches, but use the branch itself as a "label". I guess if the bug UI were better we might use labels to fill in the "where found" field, but unfortunately ours has a squllion items in the dropdown field, so it's too time consuming to fill in. We just quote the build number in the repro steps for the few cases where it is important/useful info.

Answer (score 0):

If I encountered a team doing this my first question would be why do they need to use Labels to accomplish whatever workflow they are after.  This is an unusual practice, most teams just do a Get Latest, and use an appropriate branching strategy to achieve their desired workflow.

If you must use a Label one option is to include the DeploymentScripts in your Labels.  You can do this without have to move the folder location in source control by editing your Label.

Comment: We find labels useful when we create a new branch for release and performing stabilization and bug fixes. I will check if I can add folder to a label, that will solve my issue. Thanks!